# How to keep stroke points uniform in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

I am trying to clean up a drawing in grease pencil, but I don't know how to keep the stroke points uniform, closer to each other. And also, is there a way to remove disconnect strokes turning them into a single stroke? I can take a screenshot if needed.

Sorry about my English, it's not my native language